# Returning the nth

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am testing with mocha and in the process of learning. The question is to "return the nth value of an array" although mocha continues to give me this error 
**"should return the element in that position:
     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == 0"**

I really do not understand this issue. Along with exactly is the nth position of an array.

```
x(p) {
 if(this.items[p-1]==="undefined"){
   throw new Error('out');
    }else{

     return this.items[p-1];

    }

  }
```

//Mocha Test Code

```
describe('#get(i)', function() {
    var sl;
    beforeEach(function(){
      sl = new SortedList();
    });

    it('should return an OutOfBounds exception if there is no element in that position', function() {
      try {
        sl.get(20);
      } catch (e) {
        assert.equal(e instanceof Error, true)
        assert.equal(e.message, "OutOfBounds")
        assert.throws(sl.get, Error, '/OutOfBounds/');
      }
    });

    it('should return the element in that position', function() {
      var foo = 10;
      for(let i=0; i<200; i++) {
        sl.add(foo*i);
        assert.equal(sl.get(i), foo*i);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: @ggorlen updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return `this.items[p - 1]`. Arrays are 0-indexed, that's why the `- 1` is required. If the passed value `p` is an index, then just use `p`

```
x(p) {
  return this.items[p - 1];
}
```

Or:

```
x(p) {
  return this.items[p];
}
```

Comment: Returning just this.items[p-1] still gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
x(p) {
 if(!this.items[p-1]){
   throw new Error('out');
 }else{
     return this.items[p-1];
 }
}
```

Comment: still getting this error  "should return the element in that position:
     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == 0"